# How to retrieve a count of all records where a Date field is within the next year, and store it in a variable?

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am fairly new to MS Access, but have a decent understanding of databases, with some knowledge of SQL.

I am creating a database in Access. On a main form that users will see first, I need to display a count of all records from my `Case` table, which have a `StatuteOfLimitation` date that is within the next year.

My goal was to create a label describing the information, with a button below it. The button will open a report of all of the records (this part is working fine), and I wanted the caption for the button to display the total count of how many records meet the criteria.

The only way I can think to do it, is to retrieve the count and store it into a variable. From there, I should be able to set the caption to the variable value.

I have seen a few methods of retrieving a count and storing it in a variable, but all that I found only stored a count of EVERY record, without filtering for the date range.

This was the best that I could think of, but it is not working:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim oneYearFromToday As TempVars
    SET TempVars!oneYearFromToday = (SELECT COUNT(StatuteOfLimitation) FROM Case 
    WHERE StatuteOfLimitation <= DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Date());

End Sub
```

Comment: Explain what is not working. What is the value of TempVars!oneYearFromToday?

Comment: I am getting "compile error: Expected: expression". TempVars!oneYearFromToday currently has no value, but the goal is to have it store the number of records that are due in the next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DCount()` provides a simple approach for *"How to retrieve a count of all records where a Date field is within the next year"*

```vba
Dim lngCount As Long
lngCount = DCount("*", "Case", "[StatuteOfLimitation] <= DateAdd('yyyy', 1, Date())")
```

Then you can use that count in your command button's `Caption` property.  Say the button is named `cmdOpenReport` ...

```vba
Me!cmdOpenReport.Caption = "Report " & lngCount & " cases"
```

If you want the count in a `TempVar` instead of a regular `Long` variable, declare it `As TempVar` (just one) instead of `As TempVars` (a collection).  And when you assign the value to it, don't use `Set`.

```vba
Dim oneYearFromToday As TempVar
TempVars!oneYearFromToday = DCount("*", "Case", "[StatuteOfLimitation] <= DateAdd('yyyy', 1, Date())")
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't use a tempvar to store your variable. you can try something like below using the DAO.

```
Private sub Form_Load()
dim rst         as dao.recordset
dim strSQL      as string

'Creates query string
strsql = "SELECT Count(StatueOfLimitation) as RecordCount " & _
         "FROM Case " & _
         "WHERE (((StatueOfLimitation) <= DateAdd('yyyy',1,date())));"

'Opens the query string into a recordset
set rst = currentdb.openrecordset(strsql)

'Change Labelnamehere isnto the name of the label control on your form
'Change what ever saying you want here to something you want the label to display
me.labelnamehere.caption = "What ever saying you want here " & rst![RecordCount] 'Don't need a variable storage is you can use the result here

rst.close 'closes recordset
set rst = nothing 'Clears memory

EndCode: 'Ensures clean up is successful
If not rst is nothing then
     rst.close
     set rst = nothing
end if
end sub
```

If this doesn't work for you, please let me know and I'll do some more digging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment on HansUp's answer, but to change a label caption in VBA you need to open the form in Design view.  It's not something I typically do, my personal preference is to use an unbound text box with labels that don't change, but I have done it in one database to update the time/date and user for the last email sent.

The code would look like this:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "yourformname", acDesign, , , , acHidden
    Forms![yourformname]![yourlabelname].Caption = "There are " & TempVars!onYearFromToday & " cases to view."
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "yourformname", acSaveYes
    DoCmd.OpenForm "yourformname", acNormal
```

Comment: I'm not certain whether Robert wants to change `Caption` for a label or a command button.  But, either way, the form does not have to be in Design View in order to do it.

Comment: Changing labels this way isn't something I do often, but when I use `[label].Caption = "[new text]"` the changes aren't saved when the form is closed and reopened.  That's why I open the form in design mode and make the change.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use a button for info display. That's not the purpose of a button.

Use a textbox and set its *ControlSource*:

```
=DCount("*","[Case]","[StatuteOfLimitation]<=DateAdd("yyyy",1,Date()))
```

It will fill by itself, and the button is free to open the report at any time.